# Criteria API ignore LAZY fetch

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I have two entities `Customer` and `Product` with relation one to many with lazy strategy.

Problem is fetch not lazy, products collection always fetch all related products.

```
public Optional<Customer> findById(final long customerId) {
    final EntityManager entityManager = sessionFactory.createEntityManager();
    final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<Customer> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Customer.class);
    final Root<Customer> customerMetamodel = criteriaQuery.from(Customer.class);
    criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(customerMetamodel.get("id"), customerId));
    final TypedQuery<Customer> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    return Optional.ofNullable(query.getSingleResult());
}
```

As you can see no one mention about fetch eager, and  in entity classes the same, all lazy:

Customer

```
@Data
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private int age;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Product> products;

}
```

Product

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString(exclude = "customer")
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private BigDecimal price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Customer customer;

}
```

Why lazy work as eager and how to enable real lazy mode in this case?

UPDATE_1

Integration test with H2

```
@Test
public void testFindById() {
    Customer customer = customerRepository.create(Customer.builder().age(20).name("Denis").build());
    productRepository.create(Product.builder().customer(customer).price(new BigDecimal(100)).build());
    productRepository.create(Product.builder().customer(customer).price(new BigDecimal(200)).build());
    productRepository.create(Product.builder().customer(customer).price(new BigDecimal(300)).build());


    final Customer result = customerRepository.findById(customer.getId()).orElseThrow();

    assertEquals("Denis", result.getName());
    assertThrows(LazyInitializationException.class, () -> System.out.println(result.getProducts()));
}
```

I call `.getProducts()` but expect `LazyInitializationException` because session already closed.

Comment: "products collection always fetch all related products" - are you sure? How did you check? Not by calling getProducts I hope - because that would actually trigger the lazy loading.

Comment: @mvmn Thank you for you're attention, I'm update question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using Spring? Try disabling `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans` which is an anti-pattern anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is `EntityManager` hold open session. And load subentities on demand. In my case `.getProducts()`.

For close session directly use `entityManager.close()`.